# Binding ComboBox inside DataGrid to subclass of ObservableCollection using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, combobox, observablecollection

I am writing a wpf application with MVVM design. In the View I have a datagrid with a combobox column. The datagrid is binded to an ObservableCollection of class "AdvancedSearchQueryObjType". I want to bind the Combobox within this datagrid, with a list of class "ObjTypeList". I have the list of "ObjTypeList" within "AdvancedSearchQueryObjType" and populating both on the load of view model.

But I am having difficulty in populating the Combo box. Please see my code below:

View:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgSearchQuery" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=QueryWindowDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Height="170" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
    CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category" Width="150">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding 
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource datatyp:AdvancedSearchQueryObjType}}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjTypeList}" Width="140">

                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="115" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"  Margin="3,0,0,0" 
                                Fill="{Binding Path=Icon, Converter={StaticResource   ImgConv}, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Path=Value, 
                                 RelativeSource=
                                {RelativeSource  AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                       </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
               </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
           </ComboBox>
       </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

View Model:

```
public class AddQueryViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    private void init() 
    {
        QueryWindowDetails = new ObservableCollection<AdvancedSearchQueryObjType>();
        var types = ERUSDataProvider.Instance.GetAllObjectTypeWithAttribute();
        ObjTypeList = new ObservableCollection<ObjektType>();

        types.ToList().ForEach(o => ObjTypeList.Add(new ObjektType { Key = o.Key,                                                                Value = o.Value,
                                     Image = o.Image, 
                                         Icon = o.Icon }));

        _rowCnt = 0;
        AddRow();
        _currentRow = new AdvancedSearchQueryObjType();
    }

    private void AddRow() 
    {
        RowObject = new AdvancedSearchQueryObjType();
        QueryWindowDetails.Add(RowObject);
        this.ObjTypeList.ToList().ForEach(o => RowObject.ObjTypeList.Add((ObjektType)o));
        _rowCnt += 1;
        RowObject.Id = _rowCnt;
    }
}

public class AdvancedSearchQueryObjType : ViewModelBase 
{
    private ObservableCollection<ObjektType> _objTypeList;
    private ObservableCollection<AttribType> _attribTypeList;
    private ObservableCollection<Operator> _operators;
    private ObservableCollection<bool> _conjunction;
    private bool _isNotDate;
    private bool _isNotValue;
    private Visibility _attribVisibility;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ObjektType> ObjTypeList 
    { 
        get { return _objTypeList; } 
        set { _objTypeList = value;  OnPropertyChanged("ObjTypeList"); } 
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AttribType> AttribTypeList { 
        get { return _attribTypeList; } 
        set { _attribTypeList = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged("AttribTypeList"); } 
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Operator> Operators { 
        get { return _operators; } 
        set { _operators = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged("Operator"); } 
    }

    public ObservableCollection<bool> Conjunction { 
        get { return _conjunction; } 
        set { _conjunction = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Conjunction"); } 
    }

    public bool IsNotDate {
        get { return _isNotDate; }
        set { _isNotDate = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("IsNotDate");}
    }

    public bool IsNotValue{
        get { return _isNotValue;}
        set { _isNotValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsNotValue");}
    }

    public Visibility AttribVisibility {
        get { return _attribVisibility; }
        set {_attribVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AttribVisibility");
        }
    }

    public AdvancedSearchQueryObjType() {
        ObjTypeList = new ObservableCollection<ObjektType>();
        AttribTypeList = new ObservableCollection<AttribType>();
        Operators = new ObservableCollection<Operator>();
        Conjunction = new ObservableCollection<bool>();
        IsNotDate = true;
        IsNotValue = false;
    }
}
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the DataContext binding in your combobox.

Inside a datagrid column template, the default binding points to the current item in the ItemsSource:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjTypeList}" Width="140" />
```

But since your DataTemplate is meant for **editing** (a combobox is an input control), you should place it in `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>` instead of `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>`

In `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>`, you could just show the current value:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedObjType}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedObjType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjTypeList}" Width="140" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

assuming, the current value (selection in the combobox) is a property named `SelectedObjType` in your `AdvancedSearchQueryObjType` class.

All of this is pretty well explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx), section *Binding to Data*:

> Each row in the data grid is bound to an object in the data source, and each column in the data grid is bound to a property of the data object.

Take a look aswell at http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Comment: But since the object to which I have binded the Combobox is of different class, so shouldn't the datacontext Change ???

Comment: This is what I tried to explain with "Inside a datagrid column template, the default binding points to the current item in the ItemsSource". Meaning the path of the binding with be relative to the current object in your list of AdvancedSearchQueryObjType.